# google maps v3 - styled map and switching maptypes

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'd like to have a map with 2 maptypes -- one the regular road map and the other a styled map. I've seen examples of this but today it seems that the road maptype is also displaying the styled map styles as well.

For example,
https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/maptype-styled-simple

If you switch from 'HipHop' maptype to the regular, you'll still see the styled map. This had behaved correctly in the past, just today I noticed the difference in behavior. Any remedy for this?

best,
Joe

Comment: Wow, it seems a bug of new version of Google Maps API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I confirmed it's a bug. If you set the version "v=3.9", it doesn't happen.

Comment: I reported to gmaps-api-issues tracker.
http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4590

Comment: Also, another suggestion I received was to create my road maptype as a styled map with no styles. It seems the bug does effect switching to another styled map.